# Check if input field value is File

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if value of my field is File, I try to do this:

```
$('#field_1').val() instanceof File
```

But this returns `false`. So what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine if its empty by checking the length of the files:

```
if( document.getElementById("field_1").files.length == 0 ){
    console.log("no files selected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
$('#field_1').change(function() {
    console.log(this.files[0] instanceof File);
});
```